# Can I create a multiple sockets with the same port number?

Tags: port, ipc, unix-socket

I've read that two applications/processes cannot listen to the same port at the same time. I'm wondering if unix based systems simply "deny" creating a new socket and allocating new memory(duplex) for the socket whenever App2 requests a socket with the same port number as App1.

So does it "deny" App2 like I suspect or does it go ahead and create a new socket and allocate the required socket memory for App2 anyway.

If it does allocate new memory, then how does it prevent App2 from listening. And how does the client know which socket to receive the information that the server sends since both of them use the same port. I need a lengthy explanation if possible because I'm pretty confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read that two applications/processes cannot listen to the same port at the same time.

They cannot listen on the same port **on the same network interface** at the same time, unless the `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` socket options are used. Otherwise, it is possible for them to listen on the same port **on different network interfaces**.

> So does it "deny" App2 like I suspect

Yes, the 2nd app will get an `EADDRINUSE` error from `bind()` if it cannot bind the socket to the specified interface/port.

> or does it go ahead and create a new socket and allocate the required socket memory for App2 anyway

The **socket** will have been created before the `bind()` attempt, so yes.  The socket just won't be bound to the port that is in use.

> If it does allocate new memory, then how does it prevent App2 from listening.

`listen()` will fail if the socket is not `bind()`'ed to a port.

Comment: So when the CPU context switches from App1 to App2, this time App2 will be able to bind itself  and listen to its socket normally right. And now App1 will not be able to use it's socket. The socket itself is present in the memory. But binding and listening happens only when that particular process/app is being executed else it throws an error. Assuming that there is a single network interface. Am I right to think this way